# Can't seem to handle socket.timout exception

Tags: python, xml, urllib

I've written a "little" podcast downloading program in python called [ppod](https://github.com/bamonroe/ppod) that I use to download the latest episodes of podcasts I follow. There are really 2 main steps that involve an internet connection: downloading the RSS XML page for the podcast, and downloading the audio file retrived from the parsed XML page. Either of these steps can (and often do) timeout, but for the life of me I can't seem to handle an expection to this timeout. I use the following to get the XML file:

```
import urllib.request
from socket import timeout

for i in range(1,5):
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen( url, timeout = 15)
        break
    except timeout:
        pass
```

I continually get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ppod", line 293, in <module>
    pod.getXML()
  File "/usr/local/bin/ppod", line 114, in getXML
    content = f.read().decode('UTF-8').strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 446, in read
    s = self.safe_read(self.length)
  File "/usr/line/python3.5/http/client.py", line 592, in _safe_read
    chunck =self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    reaturn self._sock.recv_into(b)
socket.timeout: timed out
```

I've also tried not qualifying the `except`, and also using `except socket.timeout` with `import socket` instead of `from socket import timeout` and I still don't get the desired behavior.

How to I handle a `socket.timeout` exception from `urllib.request`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your stack trace- none of the code you posted is in the stack trace. The problem in your code is not in this snippet.

Comment: Wow, I have the `content = f.read()` line right below the posted snippet, and I just assumed that it was the urllib timing out. I had no idea that the `read` method creates a socket that can timeout. Using the `except timeout` with a `try` block for this command solves the problem apparently...